# how to put buttons and images inside a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uibutton

Im making an ios app in xcode 4 and need to make a `UIScrollView` that contains buttons and a `UIImageView`. Does anyone know how to code this?

(I'd prefer to be able to do this in a storyboard if possible)

Thanks

Comment: **This is not related to Xcode.**

Comment: @H2CO3 Curious - since the OP states they want to use storyboards which is done in Interface Builder, wouldn't that include Xcode since IB is part of Xcode? I agree far too many questions are tagged with Xcode but this one is at least semi relevant.

Comment: @rmaddy right, but that's just user preference. Also, I'd say using IB is only good for creating simple, mostly static UIs. During last summer, I had to make an iOS app with a highly dynamic UI (it was a menu) and of course I've done it entirely from code - I'm wondering if it was at all possible to make it using IB only. Also, the *question itself* ("How to put buttons..." etc. and "I need to make this and that") is not related to Xcode. It's rather related to, say, Objective-C and the Cocoa Touch API.

Comment: yeah I taged xcode cos thats what Im doing my app in and answers that referred to any other program would not help me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the `ViewDidLoad` Method:

// Adding ScrollView

```
UIScrollView *scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)]; 
scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;
scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[self.view addSubview:scrollview];
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,960);//You Can Edit this with your requirement
```

// Adding Button

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self  action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[scrollview addSubview:button];
```

//Adding ImageView

```
UIImageView*   iv =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourPhoto.png"]];
iv.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 40,60);
[scrollview addSubview:iv];
```